# Can I use an OAuth token from backend in my frontend?

Tags: java, javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I just went through the description of [Google's DrEdit sample app](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java) in Java ([source code](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/java)). It shows how to write a simple Drive app and handles authorisation in the backend.

It's a good example but the biggest drawback I've noticed is the fact that the user is required to log in again when he wants to pick a file from his Drive (despite previously authorising the app to do that). It's inconvenient so I'd like to avoid that. Picking a file is done using the Google Picker API which is only available in Javascript.

Hence, I would like to share the authorisation information between my backend and frontend - can I just pass the OAuth token that I have in the backend to the frontend? If so, is there a recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly OK. Snooping at the client as described by @tydotg isn't really an issue since the access token is just as snoopable, regardless of whether it was generated at the client or at the server.

The only real challenge is making sure that you are only downloading a token to the correctly authenticated user. There are a number of schemes you could use to do this, but for example:-

1. User authenticates to your app using server based OAuth.
2. Server stores the user id or email in a session variable
3. When your client requests a token, you use the session user to generate a token

Comment: All right, that's what I suspected, thanks. Just to make sure I got it: when I find out that I don't have a valid token in my frontend I call the backend which either returns a valid token or requests a new one and then returns it to the frontend?

Comment: Yes. Just be careful with expired sessions

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can (I'm not too familiar with Java, but in Rails, for example, it would be easy), however the reason you wouldn't want to do this is because of security.

Anything on the server side is pretty secure and not accessible to the client. Anything on the client-side, however, is fair game. I could inspect the element and if I knew what I was looking for I could grab the OAuth token.

Answer (score 1):

Use cross identity to achieve this:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth

Comment: I read it and my understanding is: I should implement the OAuth flow in both my frontend and backend and if the application has already been authorised it will get an access token without prompting the user. Is that correct?

Comment: In my scenario the user must always authorise in the backend first so pinoyyid's answer is the one I was looking for. But this is a good alternative. It has a drawback of a pop-up window that appears for a very short time, though.